# How to return response in JSON - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have returned the response `{\"status\":1,\"order-id\":\"8D0D3EEB-69D2-432D-9CDF-5ADCD42A00FC\",\"guest-checkout\":\"TRUE\",\"}` and i am trying to get **Status**.

```
public function test()
{

      $apiurl = "****";
      $data = [
        'merchant-id' => $merchantId,
        'api-key' => $apiKey,           
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($apiurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_encode($result);

    echo $data->status;
}
```

But when i do this `data->status`, it returns empty. What could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: To turn a string (your CURL response) into an object, use `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` returns a string, so you won't be able to access it as an object.  If you want it as an object you will need to do something like this:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($result));

echo $data->status;
```

You might not even need to encode it, but without seeing the data that curl is returning I can't be sure.